# Firewalld configuration seems ignored on centos 7.3

Tags: iptables, centos7, firewalld

I would like to only permit http access for some ip ranges on my **centos 7.3** server with **firewalld**.
So here my firewalld rules

```
firewall-cmd  --list-all
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: ens160
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  sourceports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
        rule family="ipv4" source address="x.x.x.x/22" port port="80" protocol="tcp" accept
        rule family="ipv4" source address="192.168.209.0/24" port port="80" protocol="tcp" accept
        rule family="ipv4" source address="1.2.3.4/32" port port="80" protocol="tcp" reject
        rule family="ipv4" source address="0.0.0.0/0" port port="80" protocol="tcp" reject
```

But I still can access from x.x.x.x on port 80 and I don't understand why

With IP tables, here what has been created with my firewalld conf

```
Chain IN_public_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  x.x.x.x/22      anywhere             tcp dpt:http ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  X.X.X.X/16        anywhere             tcp dpt:http ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  ipgg.sdv.fr          anywhere             tcp dpt:http ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  x.x.x.x/24       anywhere             tcp dpt:http ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  x.x.x.x/24     anywhere             tcp dpt:http ctstate NEW

Chain IN_public_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
REJECT     tcp  --  ns3098611.ip-94-23-44.eu  anywhere             tcp dpt:http ctstate NEW reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http ctstate NEW reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

But it seems never taken into account.
Instead, I think this rule applied first

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

I started from scratch, here my history

1208  service docker stop
 1209  sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
 1210  sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
 1211  sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
 1214  iptables -F
 1215  iptables -X
 1216   iptables -L
 1217  service docker start
 1221  firewall-cmd  --list-all

I only see trafic passing through the Chain INPUT

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  513 38048 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 2698  382K INPUT_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 2698  382K INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 2698  382K INPUT_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    3   132 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
 2691  382K REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Answer (score 0):

Your default policy is ACCEPT, so unless there is a drop or reject rule everything will be accepted. However, more to the point it looks like your first rule specifically allows traffic from x.x.x.x to port 80?

You could also check ipv6, all your rules are for ipv4 so if ipv6 is active it may be wide open.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @user2612030 but the x.x.x.x are for security reason (don't want to publish my IPs). I don't want to get ssh disconnected if I add a reject rule for everywhere. My needs is simply to accept only http connection from IP ranges.